# Is there a way to call "Terraform init -from-module" with a branch name or git hash?

Tags: terraform

For example:

```
terraform init -from-module github.com/someone/some_repo@some_branch
```

or

```
terraform init -from-module github.com/someone/some_repo@<some git hash>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to shamanth's answer:

The documentation gives examples only for modules: https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#parameters
but the same format can be applied when using terraform init.

For example, using https:

```
github.com/some_user/some_repo?ref=my_branch_or_SHA/sub_folder_containing_HCL_files
```

Answer (score 1):

specify github url as your module source and terraform should do the rest.

```
module "consul" {
  source = "github.com/hashicorp/example"
}
```

see [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#github) for more details